# unable to create a tfrecord

Tags: tensorflow, data-science

I am unable to create a tfrecord and there is no error in the code, it was just executing when i have given this code

> python generate_tfrecords.py --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record

i have also checked the image files all are in  one folder and with the same format.
please help to create the tfrecord

Thanking you

created a images using labelImg and also did the protobuf part

there are no error but it was not creating a train record